# How can I use my local copy of Vim on a server?

Tags: vim

Like every Vim user, I have spent years tweaking my `.vimrc`. But when I connect to a server elsewhere, I'm back to plain, vanilla vim.

It's still a great editor, and I can still get things done, but I'm wondering: is there a way to edit remote files using my local copy of Vim?

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to edit remote files with vim.  You want to use `netrw`.  Do `:he netrw` in vim to learn the details.

Answer (score 5):

Copy your `.vimrc` to the server.

Many people keep their dotfiles (`.vimrc`, `.bashrc`, `.muttrc`...) in a Git/Hg repository, updated by `cron`. This way all servers always have the latest changes.

Comment: Yes, this works even better if your home directory is on an NFS mount shared by all the servers.

Comment: Pulling the latest with cron is a neat idea. I guess each user on the server could have their own .vimrc synced to their home directory...

Comment: I would like to add that I find it easiest to put *every* vim file under `.vim`, put that folder on git, and symlink any files (such as vimrc) that need to be placed elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You could investigate fuse (Filesystem in User Space) and fusefs-ssh - mount a remote directory locally using ssh.

Then you can mount the remote server's directory locally and edit the files using your local computer.